# How to get the value of amount_total of sale.order from another model?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I don't know how to get a value of current `amount_total` to convert it with myfunction, help me please.

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
import conver

class sale_total_extend(osv.Model):
   _inherit='sale.order'
   _name='sale.order'
   _description="le modele ajoute le total d'un devis en lettres"

def _amount_all_text(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    res = {}
    for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[order.id] = conver.myfunction(order.amount_total)
    return {}

_columns = {
    'amount_total_text': fields.function(_amount_all_text, string='total en lettres', type='text',store=True, multi='sums', help="Total en lettres"),
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `self.amount_total`? If it doesn't work maybe you have to override the function `_amount_all` to get the value updated

Comment: how to override the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override the function `_amount_all` try something like the following code (this example is in the `website_sale_delivery` module):

```python
class SaleOrder(orm.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    def _amount_all_wrapper(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):        
        """ Wrapper because of direct method passing as parameter for function fields """
        return self._amount_all(cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=context)

    def _amount_all(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        res = super(SaleOrder, self)._amount_all(cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=context)
        currency_pool = self.pool.get('res.currency')
        for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            line_amount = sum([line.price_subtotal for line in order.order_line if line.is_delivery])
            currency = order.pricelist_id.currency_id
            res[order.id]['amount_delivery'] = currency_pool.round(cr, uid, currency, line_amount)
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

I override the sale.order model, and make some change in function _amount_all and add a column amount_my_total to stock information after doing some operation with my_function in file my_module in python.

```
class sale_order(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    _name = 'sale.order'
    _description = ""


    def _amount_all_text(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        return self._amount_all(cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=context)

    def _amount_all(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
        cur_obj = self.pool.get('res.currency')
        res = {}
        for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res[order.id] = {
                'amount_untaxed': 0.0,
                'amount_tax': 0.0,
                'amount_total': 0.0,
                'amount_my_total':'my default value when total = 0'
            }
            val = val1 = 0.0
            cur = order.pricelist_id.currency_id
            for line in order.order_line:
                val1 += line.price_subtotal
                val += self._amount_line_tax(cr, uid, line, context=context)
            res[order.id]['amount_tax'] = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val)
            res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] = cur_obj.round(cr, uid, cur, val1)
            res[order.id]['amount_total'] = res[order.id]['amount_untaxed'] + res[order.id]['amount_tax']
            res[order.id]['amount_my_total'] = my_module.my_function(res[order.id]['amount_total'])
        return res

    _columns = {

        'amount_my_total': fields.function(_amount_all_text, string='my string', type='text',store={
        'sale.order': (lambda self, cr, uid, ids, c={}: ids, ['order_line'], 10),
            },
        multi='sums', help="my total help message"),

    }
```